# Vertical space between two tables

Tags: tables, spacing, longtable

When doing something like this:

```
\begin{longtable}{llll}
 % Stuff here
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{llll}
 % Stuff here
\end{longtable}
```

What command (I don't know the name of those, I mean like `footskip`, `topmargin`, etc.) takes care of the space between the two tabulars in this case? I would like to avoid putting a `\vspace` here, I don't like to fight with LaTeX, I always lose. :) I would like to reduce the vertical spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`longtable` does `\vspace{\LTPre}` before a table and `\vspace{\LTpost}` after a table, both of which are by default `\bigskipammount`.

Most latex display environments use `\addvspace` to add their vertical offsets, so that adjacent spaces combine (`\addvspace` just adds the maximum of any space currently on the vertical list and the space requested) but `longtable` doesn't do that so you get twice the space you would get from `\bigskip` between the tables unless you have set `\LTpre` or `\LTpost` to something else.