# How to remove unwanted space between longtable*s?

Tags: captions, longtable

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable,ltcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable*}{p{10cm}p{2cm}}
  \textbf{Lorem!} & \\
  \textbf{Ipsum!} &     
\end{longtable*}%
\begin{longtable*}{p{10cm}p{2cm}}
  \lipsum[1] & foo bar
\end{longtable*}

\end{document}
```

There is nothing between the two `longtable*` instances, so as far as I can tell, they should be placed directly next to each other (vertically). When I compile this example, I get something like this:

[image: longtables with gap]

Where does the gap between the two `longtable*`s come from and how do I get rid of it?

(In my actual application, there are some format changes that have to occur between the two tables, so I can't simply combine the two tables into a single table. I have been able to reproduce the gap without any of my extra commands.)

Comment: from `\LTpre` and `\LTpost`, see the docu or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/217620/2388

Comment: Already voted to be closed as Duplicate, thanks